# Command line only build error

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, devenv

I am trying to diagnose an error in our build.  The error does not occur on our build server or many of our dev machines, but occurs consistently on my computer and several others.  I can build the project from VS2010 with no errors.  If I use this command in the console:

```
devenv Solution.sln /Build debug
```

I get the following output:

```
------ Build started: Project: Solution, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
  Solution -> [Path]\Solution.dll
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Sometimes (seemingly random) at that point, I get a VS popup asking me to check for a solution online, close or debug.  Debugging gives me:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x596e29a8 in devenv.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x02c58bf0.
csproj.dll!596e29a8()    
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for csproj.dll]    
csproj.dll!596e2a00()    
csproj.dll!596f089a()    
oleaut32.dll!7524f786()    
oleaut32.dll!7524d398()    
rpcrt4.dll!75670966()    
rpcrt4.dll!755f4184()    
rpcrt4.dll!755f413d()    
ole32.dll!757bb1cf()    
ole32.dll!757baf19()    
ole32.dll!757bb30f()    
ole32.dll!757a55b0()    
KernelBase.dll!75580ce7()    
oleaut32.dll!75244a3e()    
oleaut32.dll!7524e40a()    
oleaut32.dll!7524e4ef()    
oleaut32.dll!7524e50d()    
ole32.dll!758aadea()    
ole32.dll!758adccd()    
ole32.dll!758adb41()    
ole32.dll!758ae1fd()    
ole32.dll!757c9367()    
ole32.dll!757c9326()    
user32.dll!75d562fa()    
user32.dll!75d56d3a()    
user32.dll!75d56ce9()    
user32.dll!75d56d91()    
user32.dll!75d577c4()    
user32.dll!75d5788a()    
ole32.dll!7578d03c()    
ole32.dll!7578d22c()    
clr.dll!6d7da27d()    
clr.dll!6d7da209()    
clr.dll!6d80e9e7()    
clr.dll!6d80eaa8()    
clr.dll!6d7da462()    
WindowsBase.ni.dll!5f4bf07a()    
mscorlib.ni.dll!6ca9dc84()    
clr.dll!6d6721bb()    
clr.dll!6d6aa7aa()    
clr.dll!6d6aa94c()    
clr.dll!6d6aa981()    
clr.dll!6d7da1c3()    
clr.dll!6d6f4795()    
clr.dll!6d80eaa8()    
clr.dll!6d80eb27()    
clr.dll!6d69173e()    
clr.dll!6d767628()    
clr.dll!6d827019()    
mscorlib.ni.dll!6caa1953()    
mscorlib.ni.dll!6caa1953()    
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.AppDomainManager.ni.dll!69d35a09()    
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.AppDomainManager.ni.dll!69d35a09()    
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.AppDomainManager.ni.dll!69d3c209()    
clr.dll!6d6725a1()    
clr.dll!6d76590b()    
clr.dll!6d7659e4()    
clr.dll!6d765a4a()    
clr.dll!6d765baf()    
004fa1e2()  
msenv.dll!6282e820()    
msenv.dll!6282e820()    
msenv.dll!6282ec04()    
msenv.dll!6282ec81()    
msenv.dll!627615e7()    
msenv.dll!6280e188()    
devenv.exe!2fac0637()    
devenv.exe!2fac0fd4()    
kernel32.dll!75c0520b()    
msvcr100.dll!_onexit(int (void)* func)
msvcr100.dll!__set_flsgetvalue()
devenv.exe!2fac20d8()    
devenv.exe!2fac2148()    
kernel32.dll!75c033aa()    
ntdll.dll!773d9ef2()    
ntdll.dll!773d9ec5()
```

Even when the error occurs, the dll and pdb files are already in the output folder and everything appears to have been built correctly.  There are several references with CopyLocal set to true and those files are also always present in the output folder.  No one has seen any runtime errors nor has anyone experienced any issues when using the binaries, regardless of whether the error occurs.  The error is also an annoyance because it pauses the build script, so we have to close the error window to continue.

I would like to determine the cause of the error or at least find a way to automatically close/not show the popup window and let the script continue.

**Edit:**

Based on Dave's suggestion, I tried MSBuild and it compiles without any errors.  That resolves the issue for me.

Comment: Could your VS be running with elevated permissions, but the cmd prompt being executed without? (Though it seems like the DLL is being accessed just incorrect/invalid offset)

Comment: This looks like an internal VS issue (as opposed to something you are doing incorrectly). I would try a repair on VS.

Comment: Why not use MSBuild Command Line to do the builds?

Comment: @Brad - Command prompt is running as Admin.

Comment: @Dave - We use MSBuild for most other solutions.  I'll give that a try.

Comment: After switching to MSBuild, I've compiled the individual solution  a dozen times and run the full script twice and haven't seen an error.  Still have to verify that it works for everyone else, but it appears that switching to MSBuild will resolve the issue.  Thanks Dave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building the project using MSBuild solved this issue.  I haven't been able to figure out why we sometimes see the error on some machines, but since I changed our script to use MSBuild for this project, no one has seen the error.  Thanks again, Dave.